# Errors on recording HTTPS resource in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I correctly installed jmeter and updated certificates for Firefox. Jmeter succesfully recorded main page on HTTPS. But when I make login into personal account on same HTTPS page, I recieve errors on in logs of jmeter and personal account does not loads.

> ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [51892]  Not implemented (probably used
> https) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex
> characters in escape (%) pattern - Error at index 0 in: "ht"

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you're trying to record plain text ([HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP)) traffic and in JMeter you use [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol.

So my expectation is that if you provide `http` as the "schemeToRecord" in JMeter's [Recording Template](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) the error should go away:

[image]

Also in case of HTTP you don't need to install any certificates.